# Unix command to find a file and rename the extension

Tags: unix

I'm new to unix and shell scripting. The requirement is such that Check for a file in the filepath declared in a variable. 
Say,

```
Filepath=/home/kvs/sample
Filename=abc.xml
```

Now I need to create a command that checks for the file in $Filepath/$Filename.
I need to cut the extension in the file name and save it in a new variable. 
Say,

```
FNAME=abc
```

Now I need to create a empty(0byte) file with the same filename in $FNAME but with the extension abc.cnf

I have tried the below.

```
Filepath=/home/kvs/sample
Filename=abc.xml
FNAME=($Filepath/$Filename | cut -f 1 -d '.'); touch($FNAME .cnf)
```

Help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$ [[ -f ${Filepath}/${Filename} ]] && { touch ${Filepath}/${Filename%.*}.cnf ; }
```

- The first part (`[[ -f ${Filepath}/${Filename} ]]`) checks if file exists. This checks for "regular files" which - I believe - is what your are looking for. There are other checks you can perform...
- The second part (`{ touch ${Filepath}/${Filename%.*}.cnf ; }`) is executed only if the file exists and creates an empty file with the same path/basename as the original file by changing the extension to .cnf.

Answer (score 0):

Try `man test` for an explanation of testing a file with `if [ -f filename]; then`.
Use `$()` as in `fname=$(echo "${filepath}/${filename}" | cut -f 1 -d '.')` when you want a second unix command right of your equal sign.
Do not get confused when people see you should use `printf`, not `echo` (first get this working).
Do not get confused when people see you should use `${filename%.*}` instead of `cut` (first get this working, nice that you found `cut`).
Use curly brackets with vars su that you can `touch ${FNAME}.cnf` without a space.
Use `ls -a .cnf` to see if you have empty files.
Use lowercase variable names, they will not collide with reserved names.
And be happy you learned something new today.

Comment: Thanks Walter. That was very helpful. fname=`echo ${filename} | cut -f 1 -d '.' `; touch ${filePath}/${fname}.cnf. This command worked.

Comment: The backtics in your comment are used for formatting the answer. How to show backticks that you use in your command? Do not use backticks in your command but choose for the slightly better new grammar `fname=$(echo ${filename} | cut -f 1 -d '.')`.
After testing this you can accept my answer.